# Ajax ping php not working if file not renamed

Tags: php, ajax, ping

I'm currently learning about "everything" and playing/messing around on a raspberry.
I'm settung up a web page to check the temperature and turn on/off the raspberry fan, to check which pc on the lan is on and turning it on if needed, etc etc...

Currently I'm on the second step: checking which pc on the LAN is on.
I'm trying with pinging, it's actually working, but there is a strange part.

Here is my main page script section:

```js
function ping(ip){
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("ip"+ip).innerHTML =this.responseText;
    }};   
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "pingA.php?ip=192.168.1."+ip, true);
 xmlhttp.send();}

window.setInterval(function(){ping(2);},500);
window.setInterval(function(){ping(55);},500);
```

```html
<p >192.168.1.2 actually is <span id="ip2"></span></p>
<p >192.168.1.55 actually is <span id="ip55"></span></p>
```

And my php file anwsering the ajax request is that pingA.php here:

```html
$ip = $_REQUEST["ip"];
$result = exec("ping -c1 -w1 ".$ip." ; echo $?");
$answer = "ON";
if ($result == 0){
  $answer = "OFF";
}
echo $answer;
```

So the result on my page is something like:

> 192.168.1.2 actually is ON
>
> 192.168.1.55 actually is OFF

Depending on the situation...

The problem is that all this is working with "pingA.php", i wanted to use "ping.php" ... but when I rename the file and the ajax call it do not work anymore!!!
Why that!?
(I was already lucky to randomly change the name of the file and discovering this...)
I did already restart apache and no change...
"ping.php" do not work... any other name, yes.
Driving me crazy.

Comment: if you look in the browser console when calling `ping.php?ip=X` do you get any errors? Does the request arrive at `ping.php` but then does the actual ping fail?

Comment: if you rename the file to `ping.php` can you access it OK in the web browser directly?

Comment: @RamRaider I'm not sure how to do that. Can you explain?
(While i was trying, that ajax request of mine (with the "wrong" ping.php name) it was giving me status 3 and then fastly 4 , responsestatus 0 (instead of 200) and responsetext empty....)

Comment: @RamRaider Yes, with ping.php or any other name i can directly write the full url to it and it will work:
A white page with a "ON" or "OFF" text on it...

Comment: if you are using Chrome ( right-click and choose `inspect` ), Firefox ( right-click `Inspect Element` ) and look at the `console` tab &/or `network` tab. Other browsers have similar developers tools - even Internet Exploder to a degree. Look for obvious errors.

Comment: Curious that you can access `ping.php?ip=a.b.c.d` etc directly in the browser and that is OK yet fails when attempted via XHR?!

Comment: @RamRaider
The actual bash/linux command (for the actual ping execution) is working fine.

It really seems like a "ping.php" name+extension combo is unaccepted as ajax (XMLHttpRequest()) request. But it make no logic for me.

(Restarted raspberry, apache... no change)

Comment: I have written own version to test this - no issues detected because of the script being called `ping.php` - using your ajax code and own it works fine so the issue likely lies with the server setup somehow...

Comment: @RamRaider
Ok, in the console/network tab i can see the other ajax requests (for temperature of raspberry) working.
Then, if I use pingA.php or whatever i can also see them!! It is shown in the list correctly (indeed it is working).

But if I use ping.php it is not even trying!!! Not shown in the list even once!

Comment: have you looked through your apache config to see if there is anything there that might be conflicting with the name `ping` ? I am unable to reproduce the issue. You might be able to do a `cheat` - in your `.htaccess` file you could create a `rewrite rule` that maps the name `ping` or `pingA.php`

Comment: @RamRaider  I was making another subdomain with a copy of the files to let you try it. It came out there it works!
It seems my current directory have a problem with any "ping.php" file, something like broken indexing (i dont know) ... 
Something is wrong linux-side.
If I try the same exact files (ping.php included) in a different folder everything works as intended.
Really strange...
I'm more interested about php/html/javascript and generally web environment... if the problem is within linux i'll ignore it for now.
Thanks for all the help! Really appreciated.

Comment: very peculiar - "these things are sent to try us" as they say!